# rest_framework.authtoken app migration error

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am not able to install rest_framework.authtoken app in custom User model.
The User model table is assigned name users with **db_table=u'user'**. While running migration of  rest_framework.authtoken gives error

> Running migrations for authtoken:
>    - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
>     authtoken:0001_initial
>   FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE "authtoken_token" ADD CONSTRAINT "user_id_refs_id_14b35167" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "users_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
>   The error was: relation "users_user" does not exist
>   Error in migration: authtoken:0001_initial
>   DatabaseError: relation "users_user" does not exist

setting have been configured in setting.py with AUTH_USER_Model="users.User". The table in database exist with name user.But, still i am receiving error. Can somebody point out my error. Thank you.